# Send GUID in custom ADFS claim rule

Tags: saml, guid, adfs, claims

Is it possible to send GUID (Active Directory field ObjectGUID) in ADFS custom claim rule as string like "00fecc2a-195e-4c88-a10b-981a6881fa00" and not encoded in base64 like "Ksz+AF4ZiEyhC5gaaIH6AA==".

```
<AttributeStatement>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier">
        <AttributeValue>00fecc2a-195e-4c88-a10b-981a6881fa00</AttributeValue>
     </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
```

Comment: Step by step tutorial to create a custom attribute store: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/cloudpfe/how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-store-for-active-directory-federation-services-3-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can use an ADFS [custom attribute store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/adfs-2.0/hh599320(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

The code is as per the screenshot [here](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2013/01/adfs-objectguid-as-claim.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is a complicated way - only to encode a base64 string. I am not a developer with visual studio. Therefore, I have to find another way.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the only way. Otherwise you have to do it on the receiver end.